# When copy paste Text field in acrobat Prepare form '#' symbol appears in each button name, Can we remove these '#' symbols using javascript?

Tags: javascript, pdf, adobe, acrobat

After page processing we noticed that in the each text field we entered (may be copy pasted) created a '#' symbol which we need to removed we have above 500 pages of document with these buttons that we need to fix.

Like "HOME#0"

Is there any script available to fix this issue.  Any help would be appreciated

[Sample Attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5BOi6.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those "#" symbols followed by the number are not really there. Those are indications ***in the UI*** only that you have more than one widget assigned to the field "HOME".

Comment: Thanks Joel,
Is there any option available to avoid '#' symbols in future when we select and duplicate text fields across multiple pages.

Comment: because I'm using "Duplicate across pages" to copy paste in one click.

Comment: When there are duplicate field widgets with the same name, you'll see the # symbols. If you want the fields to have the same name, just try to ignore the # symbols. You can't hide them. They're there to let you know what widget is selected. Remember that in PDF fields are a document level object and you can have multiple field widgets with the same name on different pages or the same page.